# Changing code at runtime

Tags: c++, assembly, runtime

I have a pointer to a function (which i get from a vtable) and I want to edit the function by changing the assembler code (changing a few bytes) at runtime. I tried using memset and also tried assigning the new value directly (something like mPtr[0] = X, mPtr[1] = Y etc.)  but I keep getting segmentation fault.
How can I change the code?

(I'm using C++)

OS is windows.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this though? surely the only reason is to reduce the amount of working memory as you can load sections of code from disc. If you explain what you are trying to do, maybe we can help.

Comment: Self-modifying code is hard.  This OS was written completely in assembly because no mid-level language has syntax to allow for self-modifying code: http://valerieaurora.org/synthesis/SynthesisOS/abs.html .

Comment: Self modifying code was popular in the 60 (especially in Russia where they made so extraordinary compilers that generated self modifying code). This style of development though was largely abandoned in the early 70s as (without compiler help) it was hard to write and nearly imposable to debug. As a result modern OS's now explicitly guard against self modifying code (with the help of hardware) as in modern languages it (self modifying code) is usually a result of coding errors or malicious code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In generally: if memory is allocated with API call VirtualAlloc than you can change the memory attributes with API call [VirtualProtect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366898(VS.85).aspx). 
Check first memory attributes with API call [VirtualQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366902(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on Operating System and/or architecture you may or may not write to executable pages.

Check documentation about marking pages as executable or read-only in the Intel (IA-32e) manuals. The code may be located in a read only section, therefore, you may not write to it.

You may mark the code not to reside in read only pages, but it's compiler specific (JIT compilers do this).

Under MSVC, you can use the [#pragma section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50bewfwa.aspx) to create a read-write section and use [#pragma alloc_text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw8ty6zf.aspx) to put functions in it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you are trying to write to the code segment, something new operating systems will prevent you to do. This is the way some viruses worked.

There are APIs to remove that protection, but they are operating system dependent.

Answer (score -1):

Memory sections where your code reside are usually marked as readonly. That's why you get segmentation failure. You can try to remove this flag from section by either special keys for compiler (not sure about that) or by modifying binary file (again, not 100% that it is possible)